# problems with Hyper-v ethernet external connection

Tags: 20.04, netplan, ifconfig, hyper-v

I am using Hyper-v with ubuntu20.04. I want to set static IP.
I created external virtual switch. I try few things to set address. Through ifconfig (ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.70/24), through netplan.
When I change from default switch to external switch eth0 is down. What I am doung wrong.

```
2: etho: <NO-CARRIER BROADCAST, MULTICAST UP> mtu 1500 con qdisc mq state down group default qlen 1000
 link/ether ..
inet 192.168.0.70/2 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
```

Comment: Hyper-V networking is a host level thing at Windows, and not an Ubuntu issue/question.  This is something that you need to handle at the Hyper-V level, it's not an Ubuntu issue if you change Hyper-V switches and no longer have connections working, it's something your'e doing wrong at the HyperV level that's likely to be your problem.  (And the Hyper-V part is offtopic here)

Comment: Well I read few tutorials for this. This is the  way to set static Ip.

Comment: You're not wrong this is how to set a static IP, but to actually get connectivity to Internet and such you need a lot more work.  Simply having an IP address doesn't work.  Also your CIDR range is wrong if you're intending to do a /24, it is clear from your putput that there's a /2 not a /24

Comment: Thomas Ward what else I need to do, would u give me a link